# Statistical tests and non-probability sampling

Tags: regression, anova, sampling

I am currently working on my dissertation. From what I learnt previously, regressions are used on data from random sampling. While I was reading others' work, I saw that some students ran ANOVA and regressions on data collected through non-probability sampling, such as snowballing and convenience sample.

I recalled that such data analysis might encounter endogeneity since the data was not randomly sampled. Therefore, I was wondering if such research method is valid and appropriate.

Comment: I think "regressions are used on data from random sampling" may be a little too sweeping: a physicist who measures how far a spring stretches when masses of 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 kg are attached and then draws a line through the results is not trying to do any form of sampling.  Similarly a plant biologist who looks at the interaction of different treatments using a Latin square design.    I suspect your question may be more about the risks when using sampling that is not random compared to when it is.

Comment: Strictly speaking and from a theoretically pure pov, results from models premised on convenience samples are compromised and invalid for the reason given. However, empirical data samples rarely, if ever, conform to theoretical requirements. What's of interest is how approaches to sampling have evolved over the last century. *Random sampling* wasn't even in most practitioners' toolkits back then. It took shocks like *Dewey Defeats Truman* headlines for it to be adopted. Most of this evolution has been driven by the economics or costs of sampling with cheaper alternatives pursued as they arose

Answer (score 8):

All statistical models are idealisations. They assume randomness, yet what is expressed in these models is never perfectly fulfilled in reality. Even the best attempt at random sampling can be criticised (you never have a perfect random sample if there are missing responses, and anyway even random number generators are not in fact really random), and there are other assumptions such as normality that will not be fulfilled. Formal assumptions "live in the world of mathematics", which is not the real world.

It is still relevant to think about how well the mathematics used for running the analysis is connected to reality, and ultimately indeed there can be problems and conclusions may be invalid because of issues with the data collection such as taking a convenience sample. To what extent this is a problem always depends on the specific situation, it can be discussed, and problematic implications for the analysis may be discovered.

So it is a good idea to try hard to do something that is "close" to idealised random sampling in the sense that you can convince yourself and others that results are reliable, and you are right criticising work where the data collection has a clear potential to produce misleading results.

But we need to acknowledge that this is not a binary issue. Model assumptions do not "have to be fulfilled and otherwise an analysis would be invalid or useless", as if this were true, we couldn't even do anything valid. Pragmatic compromises have to be made and ultimately reality is too complex for granting formal assumptions. So in any case, this requires case-specific thinking and discussion.

I should by the way add that the term "random sampling" and its relation to the formal model assumptions is not straightforward. For example, regression and ANOVA can be applied to data from designed experiments, and although there may (and often should) be *randomisation*, *random sampling* is not normally applied. Also how exactly random sampling is carried out will depend on the population to which generalisations are desired, and in many situations (such as measurements in physical experiments) the population is infinite and hypothetical, and the term "random sampling" doesn't really apply (what you have learnt may be connected to a specific application field, maybe in the social sciences, but these models are applied in a large variety of situations and issues with data collection may play out in a variety of ways).

More precisely, random sampling is not really about running the model but rather about generalisation of the results. The regression line will summarise the sample without any random sampling; the issue with random sampling is rather whether results allow general statements about a bigger population from which the sample has been drawn (including assessment of the uncertainty of results due to sampling). Such statements may be compromised by issues with random sampling. The issue is with the *interpretation* of the results.

Answer (score 8):

Many, many researchers in many fields do regression and all sorts of other statistics on non-random samples. For some such methods, there are ways to adjust things. But often the sampling is a pure convenience sample. Random sampling is often impossible (e.g. when you don't have a list of the population), or extremely expensive, or unethical or otherwise difficult or impossible.

What to do?

The regression itself is fine. The math works. What's hard is the inference from the results (including interpreting the p values, CIs and so on).

So, you can still use the regression as a representation of this sample, and you can assume that it is a random sample from some population. You can try to add control variables to deal with some of this.

Is such research "valid and appropriate"?  It can be. For instance, all the early information on smoking causing cancer was from non-random samples and non-randomized treatment (not exactly OK to randomly assign people to the smoking and non-smoking groups!)

One of my favorite statistics books is *Statistics as Principled Argument* by Robert Abelson. He argues that statistics and data analysis are not about what is absolutely right and wrong, but about what you can justify. It is part (but only part) of a principled argument. In the case of smoking, other parts of the argument were discovered over time (such as the way that the chemicals in cigarettes cause cancer).